# I am unable to get round toggle in my django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a table which contains for loop and if tag using jinja this table shows some data but in last column I want round toggle button but I only get a checkbox, I am unable to find the error please help me.

```
<tbody>
        {%for student in students%}
        {%if user.staff.class_coordinator_of  == student.division and user.staff.teacher_of_year == student.year%}
      <tr>
        <td style="color:white;">{{student.user.first_name}}</td>
        <td style="color:white;">{{student.user.last_name}}</td>
        <td style="color:white;">{{student.year}}</td>
        <td style="color:white;">{{student.division}}</td>
        <td style="color:white;">{{student.batch}}</td>
        <td>
            <label class="switch ">
                <input type="checkbox" id="" value="" checked>
                <span class="slider round"></span>
                </label>                 
        </td>
      </tr>
      {%  endif %}
      
      {%endfor%}
    </tbody>
```

**OUTPUT**

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37Xcx.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use radio button instead of checkbox so, it should be `type="radio"`.

```html
<input type="radio" id="" value="" checked>
```

Comment: @Ajay A radio button is used when you want to select only one option out of several available options, whereas A checkbox allows you to choose one or many options to be selected from a list of options.

Comment: Yes I did the same but it directly disappeared the checkbox and even didn't get a toggle button, I think this is due to other error, ill need to find it

Comment: @Ajay Maybe possible but this will work, I've also shared the article, try to restart Django server in another port as `python manage.py runserver 5000` and also try to hard refresh the server through `Ctrl+f5`.